# Rails 6 get error message from Failure monad results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monads

Is it possible to get error message which was passed as a Failure monad result? as far as I can see the `value!` method is provided for `Success` but is it possible to get message from Failure as well?

```
response[0]
=> Failure("12345 - Product code is not valid")
```

to be something like:

```
response[0].message
=> "12345 - Product code is not valid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Failure message `Failure monad` provides [failure](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-monads/1.0/result/#code-failure-code) method.

```
response[0].failure
=> "12345 - Product code is not valid"
```